# Install Custom basic laravel Package

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have created custom basic **Laravel** package and I have uploaded it on my git-hub account...

So I want to install that package from git-hub to new **Laravel** application in my local server....

I am using **Laravel** verson 5.5
Below is my `Composer.Json` code

```
{

   "name": "johnsmithamk/message",

    "version" : "0.1",
    "description": "Sample Package in Vendor folder for laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "email": "test@gmail.com"
        }
    ], 
    "require": { 
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "illuminate/support": "5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x|5.5.x",
        "johnsmithamk/message": "0.0.1.*@beta",         
    }, 

    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "test\\message\\": "src"
        }
    },

    "extra": {

        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "test\\message\\MessageServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I am installing package by using following command in terminal

`composer require johnsmithamk/message`

but after running above command I am getting following errors:--

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package johnsmithamk/message at any version for your
>   minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum
>   -stability
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, after reading your comments I believe I know what your issue is. I don't think you understand that you need two different composer.json files. You have created a package called "message" that you want to be able to use inside a Laravel project. For that package, you should use the code that you posted originally in your question, except you should remove the following line:

```
"johnsmithamk/message": "[versionnum]"
```

What you are telling Composer is that your package is a dependency of itself, which doesn't make any sense.

THEN you need to create a new composer.json in the root of your Laravel project. To THAT composer.json you have to add the code I gave you, which is:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message"
    }
],
"require": {
    "johnsmithamk/message": "dev-master"
}
```

So to summarize, the composer.json on Github is for your "message" package - it contains a list of that package's dependencies. Then you want to include that package in your new package, so that's where you add the repository config, and require your message package.

Comment: Which set? Did you try adding your repo to packagist.org or install direct from github? What error message are you getting?

Comment: I added this code 

"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message.git"
        }
    ],

    "require": { 
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "illuminate/support": "5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x|5.5.x",
        "johnsmithamk/message": "master"  
    }, 
Getting same error....

but didn't add repo to  packagist.org.. Is it mandatory to add repo to  packagist.org...?

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. This is what you need in your composer.json. Notice that I added the "https://" to the URL and the "minimum-stability" config. Take out the "php" and "illuminate/support" requirements. Those will be included in your vendor directory as dependencies of your main package - it's redundant to include them in your project composer.json as well.

Comment: Now i update composer.json file code as below
 "minimum-stability": "dev",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message.git"
        }
    ],

    "require": {
       "johnsmithamk/message": "dev-master"
    },

but getting same error :(

Comment: It doesn't look like you added "https://" in the URL section of your repository. It needs that otherwise Composer thinks the package is installed in a folder named github.com on your local filesystem.

Comment: sir, i have added https:// ,stackoverflow removing https://..

you can check composer.json code by git-hub on this url..

https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message/blob/master/composer.json